# GPUImage for live video blending

Tags: ios, video-processing, gpuimage

i want to do is

LiveCam -> filter1 = FilteredOp1

LiveCam -> filter2 = FilteredOp2

FilteredOp1 + FilteredOp2 --> on real device screen

so basically i want to process camera in two filters and whatever is the output should be given to camera
initially i thout **GPUImageFilterGroup** would help but after some experiments i realised its for chaining and not mixing.i saw some code where people are blending saved video with live cam but thats not what i want

Comment: did you ind out solution?